# Getting traceback in custom error handler in R

Tags: r, error-handling

I have a function `Stop` loaded from library `lib`. I then replace the default error handler in R with this function using `options(error = Stop)`. Within this function, I would like to get the traceback so that I may display the calls leading up to the error being thrown. However, `sys.calls` does not seem to work within a custom error handler. It only returns a single element, which is is the body of `Stop` rather than a call. This may have to do with how R intercepts the error handler with `Stop`. Furthermore, `traceback` also does not work within `Stop`. Is there some way I can get a proper traceback in a custom error handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
> fun <- function(x) stop('hello')
> Stop <- function() print(sys.calls())
> options(error=Stop)
> fun(1)
Error in fun(1) : hello
[[1]]
fun(1)

[[2]]
stop("hello")

[[3]]
(function () 
print(sys.calls()))()
```

This is on R 3.1.2.  What are you doing different?

Comment: You're right. This does work. I was getting confused because the last element is a function definition rather than a call.